# How to initialize a final Set with both Values and a Comparator without Double Brace Initialization

Tags: java

Given the following Code:

```
    private static final Set<String> set = 
        new TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER) {{
            addAll(asList("string1", "string2"));
    }};
```

How would one go about creating a set without Double Brace Initialization? I have Sonar complaining about it and can't figure out a solution due to my Set both needing values as it has to be final and having to ignore case sensitiveness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a static initializer:

```
private static final Set<String> set;

static {
    set = new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
    set.addAll(asList("string1", "string2"));
}
```

Note that making it `final` does not make the set itself immutable or unmodifiable. It's still possible to add or remove elements after the set has been initialized.

If you want to make the set unmodifiable (to make sure its contents cannot be modified after it has been initialized), you can also wrap it with `Collections.unmodifiableSet()`:

```
static {
    Set<String> s = new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
    s.addAll(asList("string1", "string2"));
    set = Collections.unmodifiableSet(s);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `Arrays.asList` is not nice: better use `Collections.addAll(set, "a", "b")`. Instead of an anonymous class initializer `{{ }}` it is better to use a static initializer `static { }`.

However listing several values is best done with a Stream (resp. IntStream e.a.).
As `Collectors.toSet()` cannot pick the constructor, use `toCollection`.

```
private static final Set<String> set =
        Stream.of("string1", "string2")
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() ->
                        new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)));
```

The mentioned `Collections.unmodifiableSet` would indeed make sense, say for a `public static final Set`- You might also provide the set as `SortedSet`.

Answer (score 1):

Using a static initializer (as in Jesper's answer) may be the best choice, but if you really want to initialize it on the same line as the declaration, you can use a private method for that:

```
private static final Set<String> set = orderedSet<>(
        String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER,
        List.of("string1", "string2"));

private static <T> SortedSet<T> orderedSet(
        Comparator<? super T> comparator,
        Collection<? extends T> c)
{
    SortedSet<T> s = new TreeSet<>(comparator);
    s.addAll(c);
    return Collections.unmodifiableSet(s);
}
```

The advantage of using this method is that you could also use it generally in any expression.